# Change URL parameters on form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in routes.rb:

```
get 'my-url/:first_param/:second_param', to: 'pages#my_page', as: 'my_page'
```

And something like this on my view:

```
<%= form_tag my_page_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= select_tag :first_param, options_for_select(@first_param_values, params[:first_param]), onchange: '$(this).closest('form).submit()' %>
  <%= select_tag :second_param, options_for_select(@second_param_values, params[:second_param]), onchange: '$(this).closest('form).submit()' %>
<% end %>
```

And i would like that form submission to set params in URL like `localhost:3000/my-url/new-first-param-value/new-second-param-value` but instead i get `localhost:3000/my-url/old-first-param-value/old-second-param-value?first_param=new-first-param-value&second_param=new-second-param-value`

Comment: That's how forms work with GET. If you want to change this behavior you need to create a JavaScript event listener that listens for the submit event and just sets `window.location` to the desired URL instead.

Comment: That's my current solution but i thought that maybe there is some other way. I looked at the "action" attribute of the form and you're right, there is no way that form knows that parts of that path are params from form fields.

Comment: No there is no linking at all between the action attributes and inputs in forms at all. Browsers just submit the form to the action and put the inputs in the query string or request body depending on the method attribute. The only way to change this behavior is with JS.